# How to send a JSON object in the response of a Node.js HTTP server?

Tags: node.js, json

I'm building a simple HTTP server using basic Node.js and I need to send a JSON object in the response to a client. I'm using the built-in http module and I'm able to send a simple string or buffer, but when I try to send JSON it throws an error.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.write({name: 'John Doe', age: 30});
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

When I make a request to this server, I get an error saying that the write method only accepts strings or buffers. How can I send a JSON object in the response?

Note: I've already tried using JSON.stringify() on the object, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify({name: 'John Doe', age: 30}));
});
```

The documentation has a similar example
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener

Comment: Strange. When I tried yesterday with JSON.stringify it didn't work. Now the same code is working. You are right. JSON.stringify is the correct answer. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways,

**Method 1:**

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify({key:"value"}));
```

**Method 2:**

```
res.json({key:"value"});
```

The second method provide more easiness to the developer where we don't need to explicity create json strings.